# Why do I get an Intermittent syntax error on this php code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get this error intermittently when executing the PHP code below. The query works in PHPMyAdmin everytime. I have tried changing quotation marks and changing the spotId to be a different type of variable but nothing seems to fix it.

Error:

> Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO spots
>   (`userId`,`desc`,`lat`,`lng`,`type`) VALUES ('3wBVC92S7VTGBOdg' at
>   line 2

PHP code:

```
  <?php

    include 'connect.php';

    $userId = $_POST['userId'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $lat = (float) $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = (float) $_POST['lng'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $difficulty = (int) $_POST['difficulty'];
    $hostility = (int) $_POST['hostility'];
    $spotId = null;
    // upload spot

    $sql = "BEGIN; 
    INSERT INTO spots (`userId`,`desc`,`lat`,`lng`,`type`) VALUES ('$userId','$desc','$lat','$lng','$type');
    SET $spotId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO diffrating (`rating`) VALUES ('$difficulty');
    INSERT INTO userdiffrating (`ratingId`,`userId`,`spotId`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$userId','$spotId');
    INSERT INTO hostrating (`rating`) VALUES ('$hostility');
    INSERT INTO userhostrating (`ratingId`,`userId`,`spotId`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$userId','$spotId');
    COMMIT;";


    //echo $sql;
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo("Spot uploaded successfully.");
     }
     else{

     echo 'Try Again';
     echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
     echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
     echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
     echo $spotId;
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
     exit;

     }

    ?>
```

Database layout:
[image: Database layout]
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If this works at all you've enabled "multi-queries" which is honestly **super dangerous**. It opens up entirely new attack vectors which are normally not an issue.

Comment: i would restart the server, there is fundamentaly something wrong , if you get that message. and of course use prepared statements

Answer (score 4):

To do this with `mysqli`, you'll need to adapt it to use placeholder values. This isn't hard:

```
$con->begin_transaction(); // Equivalent to BEGIN;

$spots_stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO spots (`userId`,`desc`,`lat`,`lng`,`type`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
$spots_stmt->bind_param('isdds', $userId, $desc, $lat, $lng, $type);
$spots_stmt->execute();

$spotId = $spots_stmt->insert_id; // Grabs LAST_INSERT_ID()

$rating_stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO userdiffrating (`ratingId`,`userId`,`spotId`) VALUES (?,?,?)');
$rating_stmt->bind_param('iii', $ratingId, $userId, $spotId);
$rating_stmt->execute();

// ...

$con->commit();
```

If you used prepared statements with placeholder values then escaping problems go away entirely. You'll have to focus on ensuring you bind the values correctly, but that's about it.

You should write queries like this **the first time, and every time** so that mistakes like the ones you've created never happen again. This isn't just a security thing, this is about respecting your time. Every second you've wasted chasing down these bugs was entirely preventable.

One thing I've done here on purpose is use *single quotes*. This disables the usual string interpolation done so if you do something like `'INSERT ... VALUES ("$x")'` because of old habits resurfacing then the worst thing that happens is you get literally `$x` in that field, you do not have an injection bug. This bug is really easy to spot since it will never work correctly, but it's basically harmless and easily fixed. Injection bugs can be overlooked and later cause catastrophic problems.

It's also worth noting that if you're not too invested in `mysqli` that you may want to consider PDO instead. It supports named placeholders, databases other than MYSQL and is all around just more pleasant to use.

Named placeholders mean you can prepare and execute against an associative array, there's no binding step. As a plus it's a lot harder to mess up the order of your inserts, or use the wrong type inadvertently.

Comment: Thank you. Should I still use $_POST to get the variables from the client?

Comment: Those are fine so long as you're aware that any user data is always suspect and **absolutely must be escaped for the context it is used in**. That is if you're rendering database data in HTML you use `html_special_chars()`, and so on. This is always done *at the time of display*, not during database insertion. Failing to do this exposes you to serious [XSS issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).